# Android App transferred to Laptop, with local php and wamp - now not registering params

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I really need your help, bit stressed so it could be overlooking mini error and just missing something.   I have been working on my app for uni on my desktop but now need to demo it tomorrow so transferred it to Laptop.   Changed IP address to laptops, transferred over php files and imported mySQL.  It is reaching the php file locally, but its saying the parameters are not been given.  The code has not changed.  What else do i need to check?  As a novice i did have complications of setting up everything on the desktop some time agao...but now i am sure i made the suitable steps for transfer but obvs not and now at a loss of my next step .

**PHP Config**

```
<?php

/**
 * Database connection variables 14/07/2016  12:52
 * define: Defines constant (cannot change)
 */
define("DB_HOST", "localhost"); //db server
define("DB_USER", "boo"); //db user
define("DB_PASSWORD", "root"); //db password
define("DB_DATABASE", "brumbooc_famvsfam");  //db name
?>
```

**PHP Connect **

```
<?php
/**
 * Handles opening and closing of the database connection
 */

class DB_Connect {
    private $conn;  //Dollar sign is a variable

    // Connecting to database
    public function connect() {  //Method
        require_once 'include/Config.php';

        // Connecting to mysql database
        $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
        // return database handler
        // Check connection


        return $this->conn;
    }
}

?>
```

**PHP LOGIN**  --- It returns error $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters email or password is missing!"; so i know the java code is connecting

```
<?php

require_once 'include/DB_Functions_Login.php';
$db = new DB_Functions_Login();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    // receiving the post params
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // get the user by email and password
    $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);

    if ($user != false) {
        // use is found
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
        $response["user"]["id"] = $user ["id"];
        $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
        $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
       echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user is not found with the credentials
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Login credentials are wrong. Please try again!";
       echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required post params is missing
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters email or password is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

**Volley request**

```
    private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
        //Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_login";

        pDialog.setMessage("Loggin in ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                PHPConfigLap.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(methodName, "Login Activity Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Create login session
                        session.setLogin(true);

                        // Now store the user in SQLite
                        String strLogInUID = jObj.getString("uid");

                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                       // String id = user.getString("id");
                        mFamilyAccount.setID(user.getInt("id"));
                        String name = user.getString("name");
                        String email = user.getString("account_email");
                        String created_at = user
                                .getString("created_at");

                        int FamID = mFamilyAccount.getId();
                           inDB.addUser(name, email, strLogInUID, created_at, FamID);

                                  Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, BaseActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                        finish();
                    } else {
                        // Error in login. Get the error message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(methodName, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("account_email", email);
                params.put("password", password);
                return params;
            }
        };

        // TODO: 09/08/2016 replace with volley standard
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req); //Old
    }
```

Comment: You are sending `account_email` from mobile and your PHP code is looking for `email`. Make both of them similar.

Comment: I just spotted that, its weird because it worked on the desktop unless i forgot i updated something..but haven't done no coding today..just stressing and setting up.

Comment: Of course it was that - not sure how it changed unless i coded some in my sleep.  Thank you so much for your response - I knew it was something really silly